# How to find all instances of manual hyphenation in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I extensively used manual hyphenation in MS Word when typesetting my dissertation, in order to work closely within a page limit. (The dissertation was quite long.)

I am now revising the dissertation to be a book, and my publisher doesn't want any manual hyphenation. All that counts is the word count, not how it's typeset in word, as the publisher will be typesetting it for print.

Is there a way to search for and remove any manual hyphenation? When I look at the document with the typesetting displayed (using the ¶ option), I can see the ¬ character which indicates a manual hyphenation spot.

When I search for this ¬ character, however, it doesn't return anything. How can I search for and replace all manual hyphenation in the document?

Comment: Why not simply select one, copy/paste & search that? If you use the standard keyboard Unicode hyphen-minus [U+002D] you cannot differentiate; if it's sensibly replaced that with a true hyphen [U+2010], you can find all in one go. If you're on Mac you can find all this info in the Character Viewer ['Show emoji & symbols'] On Win, idk how you'd check. btw, ¬ is a 'not' sign, U+00AC, often used as a 'new line' character.

Answer (score 0):

That character is the optional hyphen.

[image: IMG:]

To find it, try the following:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open Find and Replace window
- Find what: `^-`
- Click More, then select Use wildcards

Or, you can click on Special, then select Optional Hyphen to enter the string mentioned above in the Find what box.

[image: IMG:]